# Posting a nested complex type to .net core 2.0 api

Tags: c#, api

I have those classes:

```
class General
{
   public Inner Inner {get; set;}
   public String Foo {get; set;
}
class Inner
{
   public String Bar {get; set;}
}
```

In my .net core controller I want to POST a General-object:

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]General product)
{

}
```

I am posting this json-object with Postman:

```
{
    "Foo": "hola",
    "Inner": {"Bar": "hello"}
}
```

If I post this, the complex type "inner" is null in "product". The Foo-property is successfully set to "hola".

How can I post nested complex objects? With list items there is no problem.

Comment: Well, in `Inner` the key is `Bar` not `Foo`

Comment: I flagged your question as simple typographical error. Since, this won't help any one as it's not a reproducible error that people normally does. I hope I'm not wrong about the flag.

Comment: sorry guys! This was a typo. In my source code there is no mistake. I have this problem with all nested objects. I edited my question.

Answer (score 3):

That's cause `Inner` type have a property named `Bar` and not `Foo`. Thus it's not able to deserialize to Inner type. Your JSON should be

```
{
    "Foo": "hola",
    "Inner": {"Bar": "hello"}
}
```

Comment: sorry guys! This was a typo. In my source code there is no mistake. I have this problem with all nested objects. Edited.

Comment: @DavidMason that's can't be but if really it's then there is some more information you aren't sharing